# Proper JSON not received in Django Request

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, django

I have a simple API where I get the JSON data from request and parse it. The above API works fine POSTMAN but does not work with jquery.

In views.py :

```
def search_and_return(request):
    print(request.body.decode() , type(request))
    request = request.body.decode()
    request = json.loads(request)
    client_id=int(request["order_clientId"])
    start_date=request["order_start_dt"]
    end_date=request["order_end_dt"]
    print(client_id, start_date, end_date)
```

form.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Client ID</p><input type="text" name="client_id" id="clientid"><br>
        <p>Sub Client ID</p><input type="text" name="sub_client_id" placeholder="optional" id="subclientid"><br>
        <p>Start Date(And Time)</p><input type="datetime-local" name="start_date" id="startdate"><br>
        <p>End Date(And Time)</p><input type="datetime-local" name="end_date" id="enddate"><br>
        <input id="button" type="submit" name="Submit">
    </body>
</html>
```

In my javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
    $("#button").click(function() {
          $.ajax({
            url:"http://10.124.92.208:8000/customer/retrieve_info",
            crossDomain:true,
            data: {"order_clientId" : 114, "order_start_dt" : "2016-01-01T21:25:22", "order_end_dt" : "2016-01-05T21:25:22"},
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
          })
          .done(function(json){
            alert(json);
          });
    });

});
```

When I send request from POSTMAN I get below output as expected :

```
{"order_clientId" : 114, "order_start_dt" : "2016-01-01T21:25:22", "order_end_dt" : "2016-01-05T21:25:22"} <class 'django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest'>

114 2016-01-01T21:25:22 2016-01-05T21:25:22
```

When I send request from custom html or JS, I get below output and error:

```
order_clientId=114&order_start_dt=2016-01-01T21%3A25%3A22&order_end_dt=2016-01-05T21%3A25%3A22 <class 'django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest'>

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I want to receive JSON data exactly same as what I receive from POSTMAN. What changes should I make ? I think this is a issue in Javascript because POSTMAN works perfectly. What is the best way to get the data from POST request in django-views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `JSON.stringify(arr)` while parsing data

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
    $("#button").click(function() {
          $.ajax({
            url:"http://10.124.92.208:8000/customer/retrieve_info",
            crossDomain:true,
            data: JSON.stringify({"order_clientId" : 114, "order_start_dt" : "2016-01-01T21:25:22", "order_end_dt" : "2016-01-05T21:25:22"}), 
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
          })
          .done(function(json){
            alert(json);
          });
    });

});
```